# Fixing x-range not working in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plot, graph, plotly

I want to fix the x-axis range so that when you clear a trace in the legend, the x-axis range doesn't change — even if one trace has a different range.

I tried:

```
range: ["2016-05-01", "2016-05-05"]
```

Seems this should be all it takes, but the x-axis range still changes.

If I set autorange: false in the layout object, the plot fails. The x-axis values and ticks are all messed up. Why is this?

However, if I set the autorange property after the layout object definition with

```
layout_autorange_after = false;
```

Then all goes well.

HTML:

```
<div id="graph"></div>
<h3>Layout with <code>range</code> set but no <code>autorange</code></h3>
<div id="autorange"></div>
<h3>Layout with <code>range</code> set and <code>autorange: false</code></h3>
<div id="autorange-set-after"></div>
<h3>Layout with <code>range</code> set and <code>autorange</code> 
set after with <code>layout_autorange_after = false;</code></h3>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var data = 
[
    {
        x: ["2016-05-01", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-03"],
        y: [4, 5, 6],
        mode: "lines+markers",
        name: "Test",
        yaxis: "y"
    },
    {
        x: ["2016-05-02", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-05"],
        y: [10, 2, 9],
        mode: "lines+markers",
        name: "Test 2",
        yaxis: "y2"
    }
];

var layout = 
{
    height: "300",
    width: "500",
    xaxis:
    {
        showgrid: false,
        domain:[0.2,1],
        range: ["2016-05-01", "2016-05-05"],
        type:"date",
        showline:true,
    },
    yaxis:
    {
        title: "Test",
        position: 0,
        range: [3,7],
        color: "red",
        showline: true,
        showgrid: false,
    },
    yaxis2:
    {
        title: "Test 2",
        position: 0.2,
        overlaying:"y",
        range: [1,11],
        color: "blue",
        showline: true,
        showgrid: false,
    }
};

var layout_autorange = 
{
    height: "300",
    width: "500",
    xaxis:
    {
        showgrid: false,
        domain:[0.2,1],
        range: ["2016-05-01", "2016-05-05"],
        autorange: false,
        type:"date",
        showline:true,
    },
    yaxis:
    {
        title: "Test",
        position: 0,
        range: [3,7],
        color: "red",
        showline: true,
        showgrid: false,
    },
    yaxis2:
    {
        title: "Test 2",
        position: 0.2,
        overlaying:"y",
        range: [1,11],
        color: "blue",
        showline: true,
        showgrid: false,
    }
};

Plotly.plot('graph', data, layout);
Plotly.plot('autorange', data, layout_autorange);

layout_autorange_after = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(layout));
layout_autorange_after.xaxis.autorange = false;
Plotly.plot('autorange-set-after', data, layout_autorange_after)
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/mtHNWF4zTBBivmRDnwY2?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `date` as the axis `type`. From the [documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-range):

> If the axis `type` is "date", then you must convert the date to unix time in milliseconds

If you convert your dates (and adjust the x-axis slightly) it should work as expected, i.e. `autorange=false` is not required and removing one trace does not alter the axis.

```js
var data = 
[
    {
        x: [1462060800000, 1462147200000, 1462233600000],
        y: [4, 5, 6],
        mode: "lines+markers",
        name: "Test",
        yaxis: "y"
    },
    {
        x: [1462233600000, 1462320000000, 1462406400000],
        y: [10, 2, 9],
        mode: "lines+markers",
        name: "Test 2",
        yaxis: "y2"
    }
];

var layout = 
{
    height: "300",
    width: "500",
    xaxis:
    {
        showgrid: false,
        domain:[0.2,1],
        range: [1462060800000 - 6000000, 1462406400000],
        showline:true,
        type: "date"
    },
    yaxis:
    {
        title: "Test",
        position: 0,
        range: [3,7],
        color: "red",
        showline: true,
        showgrid: false,
    },
    yaxis2:
    {
        title: "Test 2",
        position: 0.2,
        overlaying:"y",
        range: [1,11],
        color: "blue",
        showline: true,
        showgrid: false,
    }
};


Plotly.plot('graph', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This also solves "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" issue for plotlyJS

YOU ARE MY HERO